# AS3 Animation won't play

Tags: actionscript-3

Fairly new to programming, slowly getting the hang of it. I've come across a problem I've spend hours on trying to fix but can't seem to get the result I'm looking for. I have made running animation for my character. He runs left, up, down, right, upRight, downRight BUT upLeft and downLeft the animations do not play. He moves in the correct direction but the animations that are being played are upRight and downRight. I've changed the animations for upLeft and downLeft to my "idle" animation and it works. I'm unsure as to why this is happening if all the other animations work correctly.

Here is my code for my player animation. Any help or advice would be great. Thanks in advance

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;


public class PlayableCharacter extends Character 
{
    private var dx:int;
    private var dy:int;
    var ready:Boolean;


    public function PlayableCharacter(x:int=0, y:int=0, dx:int = 3, dy:int = 3) 
    {
        // constructor code
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        ready = true;
        gotoAndStop("Idle");



        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnter);
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
    }

    private function onEnter(e:Event)
    {

        //doing animation stuff

        if(!leftPressed && !rightPressed && !downPressed && !upPressed)
        {
            gotoAndStop("Idle");
        }

        //Go Left
        if(leftPressed && !upPressed && !downPressed && !rightPressed)
        {
            //do something left
            goDown(-dx)
            gotoAndStop("Run");
        }

        //Go Right
        if(rightPressed && !upPressed && !downPressed && !leftPressed)
        {
            //do something right
            goDown(dx)
            gotoAndStop("Run");
        }

        //Go Up
        if(upPressed && !leftPressed && !rightPressed && !downPressed)
        {
            goUp(-dy)
            gotoAndStop("RunUp");

        }

        //Go Down
        if(downPressed && !upPressed && !rightPressed && !leftPressed)
        {
            goUp(dy)
            gotoAndStop("RunDown");
        }

        //Go UpRight
        if(rightPressed && upPressed && !leftPressed && !downPressed)
        {
            goDown(dx)
            goUp(-dy)
            gotoAndStop("UpRight");
        }

        //Go DownRight
        if(rightPressed && downPressed && !leftPressed && !upPressed)
        {
            goDown(dx)
            goUp(dy)
            gotoAndStop("DownRight");
        }

        //Go UpLeft
        if(leftPressed && upPressed && !rightPressed && !downPressed)
        {
            goDown(-dx)
            goUp(-dy)
            gotoAndStop("UpLeft");
        }

        // Go Downleft
        if(leftPressed && downPressed && !rightPressed && !upPressed)
        {
            goDown(-dx)
            goUp(dy)
            gotoAndStop("DownLeft");

        }



        if (x > stage.stageWidth)
            x = stage.stageWidth;
        else if (x < 0)
            x = 0;

        if (y > stage.stageHeight)
            y = stage.stageHeight;
        else if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
    }

    public function onStage(e:Event)
    {

    }

        public function goUp(dy:int=0)
    {
        y += dy;


        if(scaleY > 0 && dy < 0)
        {
            scaleY *= 1;
        }
        else if(scaleY < 0 && dy > 0)
        {
            scaleY *= -1;
        }


    }

        public function goDown(dx:int =0)
    {
        x += dx;


        if(scaleX > 0 && dx < 0)
        {
            scaleX *= -1;
        }
        else if(scaleX< 0 && dx > 0)
        {
            scaleX *= -1;
        }


    }


}
```

}

Comment: If changing the animation works, the problem is likely not with your posted code, and more likely with your animations. Verify that "UpLeft" and "DownLeft" animations are what you think they are.

Comment: Thanks, I've went over them over and over, changing their name's over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I dont see anything wrong with your code. I always woud advise against using labels for frames but using their numbers instead. 
The names of functions "goUp" and "goDown" are hinting in a wrong direction, I'd change them to "goVertical" and "goHorizontal". How are the leftPressed, rightPressed, ... variables set? Have you tried putting a trace inside each "if" to see if the problem is that the wrong if-block is executed or the animation is addressed wrongly? Have you double-checked the names of the frames and maybe tried it using their respective numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I've changed the animations name to the frame numbers (I didn't know you could do that) but it's much cleaner that way thank you. Although it didn't fix my issue. My leftPressed and rightPrssed variables are Booleans and are both set to False, I have a switch statement in the parent "Character" file toggling between false and true depending if their pressed. As a newbie I was thinking maybe it has to do with the fact that I don't have a "runBack" animation, I didn't add one because once I hit the left button the animation just played in the opposite direction.